# Add condition to `IN` in query

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE featured=1 and catid=$category_id or catid IN 
( SELECT id FROM #__categories WHERE parent_id=$category_id )
```

`Featured=1` works only here `catid=$category_id`. The place where starts this `catid IN 
    ( SELECT id FROM #__categories WHERE parent_id=$category_id )` outputs all rows and featured=1 is ignored at this place. How to add `featured=1` condition to `catid IN`?

So basically it looks like this by now:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE featured=1 and catid=$category_id";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid IN 
    ( SELECT id FROM #__categories WHERE parent_id=$category_id )";
```

Comment: Can you give some example what output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to force the order of evaluation that you need:

```
SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid=$category_id OR (featured=1 AND catid IN 
( SELECT id FROM #__categories WHERE parent_id=$category_id ))
```

Since `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, the expression without the parentheses was true when `(featured=1 and catid=$category_id)` was true, or `catid` was in the `IN` list specified by the subquery.

Comment: Thanks man.
`SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid=$category_id or catid IN ( SELECT id FROM #__categories WHERE parent_id=$category_id ) AND featured=1` I made like this, works well.

Comment: @user1876234 Ah, got it. I see what you wanted to achieve now - showing things that match the `IN` list only when `featured` is set to `1`

Answer (score 0):

how about a join?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE featured=1 and catid=$category_id";
$query2 = "
SELECT * FROM #__content as con
LEFT JOIN #__categories as cat
on con.cat_id =cat.category_id
WHERE cat.parent_id=$category_id;"
```